# Hidding a form element before printing

Tags: 7, forms

I want to print only bits of a very big form, my first approach was as follow:

```
function THEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user ->uid);  
    $variables['user_edit']  = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account);
    $variables['user_edit']['field_about_me'] = 'invisible';
    .....
    $variables['user_edit']['field_some_filed'] = 'invisible';

}
```

This does work to hide certain element, the problem is that there is way more elements i want to hide than elements i want to show, so this process can be tedious..

Would anyone think of a better way to do so ?

**UPDATE :** Ideally i'd like to have a function similar to drupal_get_form, but that instead only return a targeted element.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either save the elements you wish to print in temporary var, hide all (or unset them), then reassign the saved elements to $vairables array, or use [DS module](http://drupal.org/project/ds).

Answer (score 7):

if you want to hide elements the appropiate way is to set the `#access` attribute on each element to FALSE, using a `hook_form_alter()`

> '#access'
>
> Used by: All elements and forms
>
> Description: Whether the element is
>   accessible or not; when FALSE, the
>   element is not rendered and the user
>   submitted value is not taken into
>   consideration.
>
> Values: TRUE or FALSE.

Source: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#access

Comment: +1, see  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-to-hide-and-or-prevent-access-to-fields-in-a-form-such-as-group-audience-fo for an example of how the code should be written

Answer (score 3):

Remember #access will not consider the particular elements in submit process.
we can set #access to false if we want to totally ignore the fields.

In case you want to hide the field with a default value. just pass attribute in form alter:

```
$form[fldname]['#attributes']['style'][] = 'display:none;';
```