# Is it possible to hide a field on a form without writing code?

Tags: 7, forms

there are [good instructions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-to-hide-and-or-prevent-access-to-fields-in-a-form-such-as-group-audience-fo) on hiding a field using a hook.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I would like to hide a term reference field on a node edit form but use the default value for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to hide the field and have the default value saved, you should be able to simply hide the field with CSS. Find the ID of the wrapper surrounding the field and set it to `display: none;`.  Here is a working example from my D6 site:

```
#edit-field-vendor-sort-order-0-value-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This can be useful, but don't use CSS if the field value has security implications.  A malicious user could still change the value.

Comment: Very true, good point