# System settings form data access validation

Tags: 7

I have created system settings form for an image using `managed_file`.

```
$form['my_image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#name' => 'Upload Image',
  '#title' => t('Upload Image'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('my_image', ''),
  '#description' => t("Here you can upload setting image!"),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://my_image/',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg png svg jpg'),
  ),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

How can I add the file view/download access on this file based on role?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module is the answer to your case.

UPDATE: You could also use '#access' in your field definition, see [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184323/form-api-field-permission) post

Comment: Does that work for FormAPI fields?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this using hook_file_download hook-

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function my_module_file_download($uri) {
  // Allow to view/download only Authenticated user.
  global $user;
  if (in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) {
    if ($cpdf = variable_get('checklist_pdf')) {
      $file = file_load($cpdf);
      if ($file->uri == $uri) {
        return array(
          'Content-Type' => file_get_mimetype($uri),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And change upload_location as private `'#upload_location' => 'private://my_image/',`

A module is also available [Private files download permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) for this.